# How can I synchronize audio and video in real-time transcoding using ffmpeg API?

Tags: ffmpeg, transcoding

I was using ffmpeg api for realtime tanscoding, but somethimes when the system resources (memory) become limited , audio and video is out of syn, as i was tanscoding and pushing rtmp stream so it involves both decoding and and encoding , do i need some sync method to solve the problem, on whatside should i do the synchronizton, during the demux decode time or the encode push stream time,thanks in advance.

i was experencing the problem,and i don't konw how to solve the problem , i was trying to sync the pts in the demux period , read the avpacket and sync the time based on current system time,but no luck.